# Why does the use of integer variables throw an exception?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, infinity

I have come across with the following two codes. Why does it not throw an exception for floating point where as in other case it will throw a runtime exception.

```
class FloatingPoint
    {
      public static void main(String [] args)
       {
         float a=1000f;
         float b=a/0;
        System.out.println("b=" +b);
       }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:b=Infinity**.

If I try with int values then it will throw a runtime exception.
Why is it like this?

Answer (score 13):

**The short answer**

Integral types ([JLS 4.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1)) are categorically different from floating point types ([JLS 4.2.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3)). There may be similarities in behavior and operations, but there are also characteristically distinguishing differences such that confusing the two can lead to many pitfalls.

The difference in behavior upon division by zero is just one of these differences. Thus, the short answer is that Java behaves this way because the language says so.

---

#### On integral and floating point values

The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:

- `byte`: from `-128` to `127`, inclusive, i.e. `[-2`<sup>`7`</sup>`, 2`<sup>`7`</sup>`-1]`
- `short`: from `-32768` to `32767`, inclusive,  i.e. `[-2`<sup>`15`</sup>`, 2`<sup>`15`</sup>`-1]`
- `int`: from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, inclusive, i.e. `[-2`<sup>`31`</sup>`, 2`<sup>`31`</sup>`-1]`
- `long`: from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`, inclusive, i.e. `[-2`<sup>`63`</sup>`, 2`<sup>`63`</sup>`-1]`
- `char`, from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from `0` to `65535`, i.e. `[0, 2`<sup>`16`</sup>`-1]`

The floating-point types are `float` and `double`, which are conceptually associated with the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision 64-bit format [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) values and operations.

Their values are ordered as follows, from smallest to greatest:

- negative infinity,
- negative finite nonzero values,
- positive and negative zero (i.e. `0.0 == -0.0`),
- positive finite nonzero values, and
- positive infinity.

Additionally, there are special *Not-a-Number* (`NaN`) values, which are *unordered*. This means that if either (or both!) operand is `NaN`:

- numerical comparison operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` return `false`
- numerical equality operator `==` returns `false`
- numerical inequality operator `!=` returns `true`

In particular, `x != x` is `true` if and only if `x` is `NaN`.

For e.g. `double`, the infinities and `NaN` can be referred to as:

- [`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY)
- [`Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
- [`Double.NaN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN), testable with helper method [`boolean isNaN(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29)

The situation is analogous with `float` and [`Float`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html).

---

#### On when exceptions may be thrown

Numerical operations may only throw an `Exception` in these cases:

1. `NullPointerException`, if unboxing conversion of a `null` reference is required
2. `ArithmeticException`, if the right hand side is zero for *integer* divide/remainder operations
3. `OutOfMemoryError`, if boxing conversion is required and there is not sufficient memory

They are ordered by importance, with regards to being common source for pitfalls. Generally speaking:

- Be especially careful with box types, as just like all other reference types, they may be `null`
- Be especially careful with the right hand side of an integer division/remainder operations
- Arithmetic overflow/underflow *DOES NOT* cause an exception to be thrown
- Loss of precision *DOES NOT* cause an exception to be thrown
- A mathematically indefinite floating point operation *DOES NOT* cause an exception to be thrown

---

#### On division by zero

For *integer* operation:

- Division and remainder operations throws `ArithmeticException` if the right hand side is zero

For *floating point* operation:

- If the left operand is `NaN` or `0`, the result is `NaN`.
- If the operation is *division*, it overflows and the result is a signed infinity
- If the operation is *remainder*, the result is `NaN`

The general rule for all floating point operation is as follows:

- An operation that overflows produces a signed infinity.
- An operation that underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero.
- An operation that has no mathematically definite result produces `NaN`.
- All numeric operations with `NaN` as an operand produce `NaN` as a result.

---

#### Appendix

There are still many issues not covered by this already long answer, but readers are encouraged to browse related questions and referenced materials.

#### Related questions

- [What do these three special floating-point values mean: positive infinity, negative infinity, NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007586/what-do-these-three-special-floating-point-values-mean-positive-infinity-negati)
- [In Java what does NaN mean.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean)
- [When can Java produce a NaN (with specific code question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887131/when-can-java-produce-a-nan-with-specific-code-question)
- [Why does (360 / 24) / 60 = 0 … in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475652/why-does-360-24-60-0-in-java/) (distinguish integer vs floating point operations!)
- [Why null == 0 throws NullPointerException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-null-0-throws-nullpointerexception-in-java/) (beware the danger of boxed primitives!)
- [Is 1/0 a legal Java expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934063/is-1-0-a-legal-java-expression) (absolutely!!!)

Comment: Please suggest corrections as comments; I'll incorporate them into the answer with next revision, along with other feedbacks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749375/arithmeticexception-thrown-during-bigdecimal-divide ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0

Answer (score 12):

Because floats actually *have* a representation for the "number" you're trying to calculate. So it uses that. An integer has no such representation.

Java (mostly) follows IEEE754 for its floating point support, see [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.3) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is because integer arithmetic always wraps it's result except for the case of (Division/Remainder By Zero).
In case of float, when there is an overflow or underflow, the wrapping goes to 0, infinity or NaN.
During the overflow, it gives infinity and during underflow, it gives 0.
Again there are positive & negative overflow/underflow.
Try:

```
float a = -1000;
float b = a/0;
System.out.println("b=" +b);
```

This gives a negative overflow

Output

> b=-Infinity

Similarly positive underflow will result in 0 and negative underflow in -0.
Certain operations can also result in returning a NaN(Not a Number) by float/double.
For eg:

```
float a = -1000;
double b = Math.sqrt(a);
System.out.println("b=" +b);
```

Output

> b=NaN

Answer (score 1):

It's a programming and math standard for representing / by zero values. float has support for representing such values in JAVA. int (integer) data type doesn't have way to represent same in JAVA.

Check :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

http://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/0by0.html