# Arithmetic Exception: / by zero only works on integers in Java

Tags: java, exception, casting, floating-point, integer

Why such different answers on dividing a number by zero:

My code:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    int a = (int)(3/0.0F);
    System.out.println(a);

    System.out.println(3/0.0F);

    System.out.println(3/0);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2147483647
Infinity
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Every time I divide a number by an integer (byte, short, int, long) it throws ArithmeticException, which is not the case when done with real numbers (float, double). Why?

Comment: Because floating-point is designed to return NaN in that circumstance. This is an out-of-band value. There are no out-band values for integers so an exception is required.

Comment: In case you didn't know OP - NaN stands for "Not a Number".

Comment: @EJP - I wonder why they have different rules for floats and integers in case of division by zero.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev I just answered that.

Comment: @EJP in that case, why the first statement didn't throw an exception on type casting?

Comment: Just so you know, the `2147483647` output is because you're casting infinity (as shown in next output) to an integer, so it is going to keeping rolling over the integer range and end up at the largest possible value (2^31-1 or 2147483647)

Comment: @HimanshuAggarwal [JLS #5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):"The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type int or long."

Comment: i got that. thanks @EJP and mike

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the use of integer variables throw an exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380749/why-does-the-use-of-integer-variables-throw-an-exception)

Comment: @EJP A finite number divided by zero does not produce NaN but an infinity in floating-point. Only 0.0/0.0 produces NaN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [JLS §15.17.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2):

> - Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.

with the exception that:

> if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an
>   ArithmeticException is thrown.

Comment: The obvious question is "Why did they write the specification in a way that does not treat floating point and integer arithmetic congruently?"

Comment: @mikez The obvious answer is "IEEE 754", and the lack of a way to implement that for integers because there is no integral `NaN.`