# Why getting Double.isNan() value as False in below scenario?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain why the flag value is returning False?

```
double a = 1.0;
double b = 0.0;
double c = a / b;
boolean flag = Double.isNaN(c);
System.out.println(flag); // False?
System.out.println(c); // Infinity
```

Comment: I've reopened this because the previously linked duplicate is answering a different question and doesn't cover this case.

Comment: see http://javaconceptoftheday.com/isnan-and-isinfinite-methods-java/

Comment: Because infinity isn't a `NaN`?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007586/what-do-these-three-special-floating-point-values-mean-positive-infinity-negat

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the definition of floating-point representation in the IEEE 754 standard.  The standard has representations for both "infinity" and "NaN".  "Infinity" is for operations that either produce an infinite result (such as 1/0 or tan(pi/2) [*]) or produce a result whose absolute value is larger than the largest possible number the format can represent.  More precisely, in math, there really isn't such a thing as an infinite result; rather, it's defined in terms of limits.  Thus, 1/0 doesn't exist, but the limit of 1/x as x approaches 0 is infinite.

NaN is returned for "indeterminate forms".  In math, these are cases such as 0/0 when the limit can't be determined just by looking at the numerator and denominator.  (If you have two functions f(x) and g(x) where the values are both 0 at some point f(a)=g(a)=0, then you can't determine the limit of f(x)/g(x) as x approaches a, without extra work such as L'Hopital's rule.)  NaN is also returned for things like taking the square root of a negative number.

In Java, `isNan` returns true only for actual NaN's, not for infinities.  Even though infinity really is "not a number", it doesn't meet the definition of a NaN according to the IEEE standard.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN) for a definition of which operations generate NaN.

[*] Note that "pi" can't be represented exactly in a floating-point number, so this really isn't an operation that could produce an "infinite result" on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the IEEE-754 standard says. When you divide a non-zero floating point number by zero, it does not return a number, but `infinity`.

Take a look at this: http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#exceptions

Comment: "When you divide a floating point number by zero" should be "When you divide a non-zero floating point number by zero".  0/0 will return a NaN.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Edited. Thanks! :)